# jp@gc - Graphs Generator not generating graphs in jmeter

Tags: performance, plugins, jmeter, performance-testing

I have added two listeners

1) **View results in tree**

[image]

2) **jp@gc - Graphs Generator**

[image]

CSV is getting generated from 1st listener but 2nd listener is not generating any graphs even though all my path is correct

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of Graph Creator

Comment: can you check is there any error present in the log file? jmeter.log or in GUI, top-right corner(right side to time input)

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled across the same problem, here's the solution.

Jmeter sometimes does not show the error count/message in the caution area at the top right corner of the GUI.
I anyway went ahead and checked the log file, it seems that the error was java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.SynthesisReportGui , hence the graphs were not getting generated.

Install extras plugin from http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/file/JMeterPlugins-Extras-1.2.1.zip and place it in the lib/ext folder and restart the jmeter. Hopefully this resolves the issue.

Other thing to keep in mind is that the view result tree should be placed above the generate graph listener.

Comment: Just to add on, your link should be https instead of http. I almost thought the link was dead/expired.